# XSLT for selecting nodes in xml based on condition 'if node != null''

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XML file having structure is as follows-

```
<products>
 <product>
   <ptype>fruits</ptype>
   <varieties>
     <variety>
       <id>a</id>
       <cost>100</cost>
     </variety>
     <subvarieties>
       <variety>
         <id>b</id>
         <cost>100</cost>
       </variety>
       <subvarieties>
         <variety>
           <id>c</id>
           <cost>100</cost>
         </variety> 
       </subvarieties>
       </variety>
     </subvarieties>
     <variety>
       <id>d</id>
       <cost>75</cost>
     </variety>
   </varieties>
 </product>
 <product>
   <type>vegetables</type>
   <varieties>
     <variety>
       <id>e</id>
       <cost>50</cost>
     </variety>
   </varieties>
 </product>
```

I need to restructure the above xml into HTML tabular format based on node `<variety>`. It means irrespective of the position of the node `<variety>` in XML, I need to select the elements under that node. Sometime the node might be empty i.e no elements under the node. Desired XML is as follows -

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
     <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>100</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>100</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>100</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>75</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>50</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Attempted XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="/products">
        <xsl:for-each select="//variety">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting an empty response for the above XSLT. Any help would be a great plus.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="/products">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//variety">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="cost" /></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRJB)

Comment: I have an empty node for node <variety>. In the response it should not return an empty tag. Also in my original XML, under <variety> i have a few elements having same name. So i choose the format <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Please post a valid XML example that has all these special cases you mentioned and the expected output.